# How to open CardView Layout in OnclickItemListener in ListActivity?

Tags: android, listview, android-cardview, onitemclicklistener

I am a beginner in Android.. I'm trying to Open CardView Layout on ListView's OnClickItemListener.Where CardView consist of same XML but different Content which will be extracted from String Array.
  Is it Possible.??

Comment: Have you tried? Post some code please

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler  umm.. No i had just did a paper work.. Is it Possible..??